# ¿Cómo evitar que se forme un bucle infinito?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy realizando una práctica de programación en Java, y el tipo de variable tiene las siguientes características:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;public class Habitante {
String nombre;
ArrayList<Producto> cesta;
double vigor;
char sexo;
static ArrayList<Habitante> poblacion=new ArrayList<Habitante>();
```

Para crear un nuevo habitante, hay que pasarle por parámetros un nombre y un sexo, y se le asigna por defecto un vigor concreto. El problema viene cuando piden que, al añadir un habitante, este entre dentro del ArrayList poblacion. Cuando por el constructor se le pasa  un habitante, al ir a añadirlo en el ArrayList poblacion se crea un bucle, que no sé cómo evitar.

```
public Habitante(String s, char c) {
    if(c!='H' && c!='M') sexo = 'H';
    vigor=100;
    cesta=new ArrayList<Producto>();
    poblacion.add(new Habitante(s,c));
}
```

El error que me sale cuando compilo es:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Habitante.<init>(Habitante.java:16)
```

repitiéndose la parte de at Habitante.(Habitante.java:16).

Comment: cual es la línea 16?

Comment: poblacion.add(new Habitante(s,c));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu error se encuentra en esta sentencia

```
static ArrayList<Habitante> poblacion=new ArrayList<Habitante>();
```

Estás declarando tu ArrayList como estático. Eso puede estar causando el problema, quítale el atributo estático.

Además de que el ArrayList está siendo creado de manera redundante. Deberia declararse de la siguiente manera:

```
ArrayList<Habitante> poblacion=new ArrayList<>();
```

Si tu objetivo es crear un objeto Habitante y con ello, añadirlo a un ArrayList de objetos Habitantes, el siguiente código debería servirte:

```
class Habitante {
//Atributos de la clase Habitante
private String s;
private char c;
//Su constructor
public Habitante(String s, char c) {
    //Cada habitante tendrá un atributo vigor de 100
    int vigor = 100;
    this.c = c;
    this.s = s;
}
}
```

Nuestra clase MAIN será:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Inicializaamos los valores
    String s = "A";
    char c = 'a';
    //Nos creamos un ArrayList de objetos Habitante
    ArrayList<Habitante> poblacion = new ArrayList<>();
    //Llamamos al método add y nos creamos un objeto Habitante, entrándole 
    //por constructor los dos atributos declarados.
    poblacion.add(new Habitante(s, c));

}
```

Comment: En la práctica ponen como restricción que el ArrayList tiene que ser estático. He llegado a la conclusión que tengo que crear una nueva variable tipo Habitante (de nombre "hab", por ejemplo), inicializarla, y en lugar de  la ultima línea, poner poblacion.add(hab).

Comment: ¿Tu práctica simplemente te pide crear un objeto Habitante y añadirlo a un ArrayList? Lo editaré en la respuesta

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que pide y ya lo he puesto en la práctica y está perfecto. Muchas gracias.